# How do I access a checkbox with ruby capybara/selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, site-prism

My usual method of obtaining a checkbox doesn't appear to be working here... Basically I have a table with some data in it but the first `td` is a checkbox. What I am trying to do is click on that checkbox, yet no mater what I do, it seems to not be present on the screen or at least it is not clickable. I've tried using xpath with `td[1]`, `td[1]/input`, `td[1]/input[@data-role="checkbox"]` and a number of other permutations but no luck... I am using SitePrism and within the row already so I should be able to get right to these elements. For example using `td[2]` with `.text` gives me `Foo` no problem... But it is almost as if the checkbox is not there.

Additionally if I try doing `all('input').size` or `all('label').size` I am getting 0, which indicates to me that those aren't rendering despite clearly being displayed on the page and inspected via chrome dev tools.

```
<tr data-uid="123" role="row" class="state-selected" tabindex="1008">
    <td aria-describedby="75e50a2e-9354-43aa-90af-231170f41b4f" role="gridcell">
        <input class="k-checkbox" data-role="checkbox" id="3a3d214a-9e48-4c3e-869d-9821b42ded19" aria-label="Select row" aria-checked="false" type="checkbox" tabindex="-1">
        <label for="3a3d214a-9e48-4c3e-869d-9821b42ded19" class="k-checkbox-label k-no-text">&#8203;</label>
    </td>
    <td class="gridDataString" tabindex="-1" aria-describedby="6e767f1c-78a3-4988-9633-17bcab112766" role="gridcell">
        <span>Foo</span>
    </td>
    <td class="gridDataString" tabindex="-1" aria-describedby="2f654308-1ddb-4f54-a3bf-2d6c36980378" role="gridcell">
        <span>Bar</span>
    </td>
    <td class="gridDataString" tabindex="-1" aria-describedby="3ae4ac0a-e16d-4892-b8ad-a821adeb55ee" role="gridcell">
        <span></span>
    </td>
    <td class="gridDataString" tabindex="-1" aria-describedby="f443994b-3e0f-4e8e-a658-f5efe839bb5e" role="gridcell">
        <span>Foo Barrr</span></td>
    <td class="gridDataString" tabindex="-1" style="display:none" aria-describedby="0f49ae1e-765e-4f99-83b1-46aa3067ac5f" role="gridcell">
        <span ng-bind="dataItem.modelId">0x0000000000004701,0x00000000000811f9,</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the actual checkbox element isn't visible on the page and has been hidden via CSS to replace with an image for styling reasons. Check the styles applied to the actual checkbox element for `display: none`, `opacity: 0`, etc.

To work with this you can either click the label element associated with the checkbox or  pass the `allow_label_click` element to `check` to have it click the associated label when the actual checkbox is unclickable. Another potential option if there isn't a visible associated label element is to just click the `td` element - which will trigger a click in the middle of the `td` which should actually hit the checkbox replacement.  Assuming you have the row element already (`tr`) one of the following should work

```
tr.check(class: 'k-checkbox', allow_label_click: true)
tr.find('label.k-checkbox-label').click
```

Not as understandable but may work/be necessary in some cases

```
tr.find('td:first-child').click
```